# How Can I get next 6th date every time using javascript & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

```js
function sixthDate() {
  var curr = new Date(); // get current date
  curr.setDate(curr.getDate() + 6);
  return curr;
}
console.log(sixthDate());
```

It is just showing me same 6th date every time! But I want the next 6th date everytime I call ( like : 18 june 2020 + 6 = 24 june 2020 , 24 june + 6 = 30 june ).

Comment: I'm new in JavaScript can you help me to find out this problem via moment.js or JavaScript

Comment: Your function works for me in Chrome. I see `"2020-06-23T19:36:56.858Z"`

Comment: your code works fine

Comment: It shows the same day because you always *start* counting from the same day (today).

Comment: @sumanbiswas Your normal function won't be remembering the value of variables after the last call. For what you are expecting, you would have to use function closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for a **[function closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)** here. Using this, you will be able to store the date that you initially called the function and then each time you call it again, it will print the 6th date after the last printed 6th date.

```js
function sixthDate() {
  var curr = new Date(); // get current date
  curr.setDate(curr.getDate() + 6);
  return curr;
}

console.log("Normal function - ");
//prints same 6th dates everytime
console.log(sixthDate().toDateString());
console.log(sixthDate().toDateString());

const getNewSixthDate = function() {
  var curr = new Date;
  return function() {
    curr.setDate(curr.getDate() + 6);
    // returning a copy and not the reference
    // so that curr doesn't get modified outside function
    return new Date(curr);
  }
}();


console.log("\nUsing Function Closures -");
// prints the 6th date, stores it
// and then prints the 6th date after that next time
// This process will repeat everytime
console.log(getNewSixthDate().toDateString());
console.log(getNewSixthDate().toDateString());
console.log(getNewSixthDate().toDateString());
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This is what i Looking for !

Comment: @RobG Yea, right! Thanks for suggesting that, made the edit.